# npm not defaulting local installs to ./node_modules

Tags: npm

When I try to do a local install (eg. `npm install socket.io`), it's putting the module in the `~/src/node_modules/` folder. `npm root` reports this folder as well. I must have screwed up npm's settings during some bleary eyed late night session, but I can't figure out how to get it set back to `./node_modules` as the default. Anyone know what I screwed up, and how to set it back to the default?

**Update**

I have tried `npm config set root ./node_modules` but `npm root` still reports `~/src/node_modules` as the root. I also checked .bash_profile and no node related settings are being made in it.

Comment: `npm uninstall npm` and then a reinstall should make it go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick `npm uninstall npm -g` and then another install from the npm website should get your defaults back.

Normally reinstalling is a pain but with your package.json files you can get everything set back up with a quick `npm link`